# Sending via Mailgun API as MIME, without Mailgun library

Tags: php, curl, mailgun, php-curl

I'm using PHPMailer to build an e-mail as a MIME string, and I want to send it via the Mailgun API, using `curl` to connect to the `/v3/[mydomain]/messages.mime` endpoint.

[Mailgun documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending) says the MIME string has to be sent as the `message` parameter, and that you must use `multipart/form-data` to send it as a file upload.

[libcurl documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php) says that if you give an array to the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option, the Content-type will be set as `multipart/form-data`.

I tried this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ["message" => $mimeData]);
```

But the Mailgun API answers as follows:

```
{ "message": "'message' parameter is not a file" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by first creating a temporary file:

```
$mimeFile = tmpfile();
fwrite($mimeFile, $mimeData);
```

And passing it to a CURLFile:

```
$mime = new \CURLFile(stream_get_meta_data($mimeFile)['uri']);
```

After this, I got a new error message, `'to' parameter is missing`, so I finally had to get the recipient addresses from PHPMailer (they are already in the MIME string, but the API doesn't seem to realize it):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    "to" => implode(", ", array_keys($this->getAllRecipientAddresses())),
    "message" => $mime
]);
```